# Has anyone created keybindings in Meteor successfully?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've been trying to implement keybindings in Meteor for a while. I tried the following package:

https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-keybindings

But no matter what I do it keeps saying that the methods (e.g. add keybinding) is undefined. So I was thinking of using another method.

Has anyone created keybindings in Meteor successfully? Say, triggering an event by pressing alt + a?

Comment: Have you tried reporting the problem to the package developer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean key events anywhere on the page, not just inside an input field, I use the method below to add these callbacks to the window. you then have to manually remove them too on closing that route.

on the mac, control keys etc just work to send different keycodes.
however, I haven't had success with this on windows yet - don't have a machine here to test and trying briefly didn't seem to elicit key responses. However i think that's more of a jquery/browser thing that anything meteor related. Let me know if you find useful keycodes on windows for Ctrl-S etc (or alt-S)!

onRun and onStop should only get called once, but i find events in iron;router a bit unpredictable, so it's worth adding in your own checks for initDone=true/false.

```
#coffeescript 

#--- router
  Router.map ->

    @route 'myTemplate',
      path: '/some/path'

      onRun: ->
        Template.komikPlayer.initScene()

      onStop: ->
        Template.komikPlayer.exitScene()
```

then in the relevant view template have init and exit events to setup/teardown the key events

```
    Template.myTemplate.initScene = () ->
      addKeyEvents()

    Template.myTemplate.exitScene = () ->
      removeKeyEvents()

    addKeyEvents = () ->
      console.log('addKeyEvents')
      $(window).on 'keydown', (e) -> handleKeys(e)

    handleKeys = (e) ->
      switch e.keyCode
        when 69
          console.log('edit')
          url = "/komikEditScene/#{comic.data.params.chapter}/#{comic.data.params.scene}"
          window.open(url, 'editor')
        when 39, 32, 13 # next
          navTo("#nextField")
        when 37 # back
          navTo("#backField")
        else
          console.log('unused key:', e.keyCode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is helpful, but I am using a simple keypress detection in the events area of my js file. This only works if the input field is selected.

```
//keypress input detection for autofilling form with test data

    'keypress input': function(e) {

        if (e.which === 17) { //17 is ctrl + q

            fillForm();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Are you using that in Meteor? I can put that code in any template?

Comment: If you did decide to use something like this and you use a mac I wouldn't use ctrl + q, because on a mac, that closes the app. (Just an FYI).

Comment: Yes, I'm using it in meteor, you can put it in the template.name.events({ }); area of your .js file. See an example here. https://github.com/c316/give/blob/master/client/views/donation_form/donation_form.js

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it when I arrive home.

Comment: Also, this might help you figure out what to use. https://www.west-wind.com/WestwindWebToolkit/samples/Ajax/Html5AndCss3/KeyCodeChecker.aspx

Comment: note this will only work on input fields, whereas my answer above will give you all events on the page.